# Why aren't the protagonists in Mouse Hunt hurt by their mishaps?

Tags: mouse-hunt

Do the protagonists (Ernie Smuts and Lars Smuts) have some kind of [toon force](https://vsbattles.fandom.com/wiki/Toon_Force)?

Ernie climbed up a chimney, the mouse puts the gas on and Lars lit a match and Ernie turned into a flaming fireball and landed in the water but survived **as if nothing had happened.**

Comment: As far as I am aware Mouse Hunt is neither scifi nor fantasy and so I am voting to close as off topic.

Comment: But isnt it slightly fantasy?

Comment: @Porkklingon - The behaviour of the titular mouse seems deeply abnormal *within that universe* which means that it falls into the broad category of fantasy

Comment: I believe it's the same mystical force that protected the Three Stooges from quite a bit of damage over the years.

Answer (score 5):

The slapstick antics of the human characters are not harmless for any good in-universe reason.  They operate purely on what TV Tropes calls "[Rule of Funny](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny)":  *The limit of the Willing Suspension of Disbelief for a given element is directly proportional to its funniness.  Any violation of continuity, logic, physics, or common sense is permissible if the result gets enough of a laugh.  This is the comedy equivalent of the Rule of Cool....*

It is pretty common in comedies for individuals to be subjected to the kinds of injuries that might be serious, debilitating, or even fatal in real life—yet after a brief daze, the affected characters dust themselves off and are no worse for wear.  This is especially common in cartoons, and *Mouse Hunt* has a very cartoonish esthetic.  The travails of the human protagonists are quite reminiscent of the old cartoon duels between Buggs Bunny and Elmer Fudd, or (the highly anthropomorphic) Donald Duck versus (the much more animal-like) Chip and Dale.  In fact, *Mouse Hunt* might be best thought of as an example from the cartoon genre, which just happens to have been made in live action.

Comment: This answer would be dramatically improved by providing a quote from the makers (or the studio) identifying it as "slapstick"

Comment: @Valorum Huh? Something can validly be described as "slapstick" or anything else without the person who made it saying so.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - No, but learning the intent of the makers would improve the answer, as would learning that the humans in this world are effective immortal *for a different  reason*.